# Postselection and hardness of estimating amplitudes

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, complexity-theory

Let $A$ be a class of quantum circuits such that

\begin{equation}
\text{Post}A = \text{Post}BQP,
\end{equation}
where $\text{Post}$ indicates post-selection. Is only this amount of information sufficient to conclude that it is $\# P$ hard to estimate each output amplitude of a circuit in the class $A$, in the worst case, upto an inverse polynomial multiplicative error?

Note that it should be $\# P$ hard to compute each output amplitude of a circuit in $\text{Post}BQP$ upto inverse polynomial multiplicative error (as it is $\# P$ hard to compute each output amplitude of a circuit in $BQP$ upto the same error).